# SSAS Dimension attribute as Calculated Measure

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I am having some issues trying to implement an average of a dimension attribute.

The basic structure is:

- Booking Header Dimension
- Fact Table (multiple rows per Booking Header
  entry)

On the booking header dimension I have a numerical attribute called Booking Window, and I want to be able to create a calculated measure that averages this value.

We are using SQL Server 2012 standard edition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure this really makes much sense. You say you want to create an average of a dimension attribute. What sort of query do you wish to write?

You can create an Average as a Measure (so any column in your Fact table). You can't create an average for a dimension attribute.

If you can provide more details about what you are trying to achieve we can hopefully provide more help.

Ash

Comment: In order to retain appropriate granularity in the fact table, I could not include booking window in the fact table. I am trying to do the average of the booking window that is in the dimension, I have seen quite a few examples of this been done, so I know it is possible. Exactly how to do it is eluding me at the moment

Comment: Could you give me in plain English the sort of query you want to perform? If you want an average of the Booking Window attribute, that suggests you have a range of Booking Window members over which you wish to perform the average. Is this range fixed (for example the average over every memmber) or is it subject to user selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a measure group from the dimension table (in BIDS, go to cube designer, tab "Cube Structure", right-click the cube object in the Measures list, and select "New Measure Group", select your dimension table). BIDS will generate some measures, and you can remove all but two: the one based on your numeric attribute (I will call it "YourSummedAttrib" to have a name to refer to below), and the count measure. The aggregate function for the measure "YourSummedAttrib" will probably be "sum", leave that as it is.

Then, create a calculated measure which divides "YourSummedAttrib" by the count measure, which gives the average. Finally, if you have tested everything, make the two measures "YourSummedAttrib" and the count measure invisible before you give the cube to the users, as they only need to see the average, which is the calculated measure.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for this, and this is the approach I have tried before, however, the issue I have here is that it just doesn't scope to anything. i.e. it shows the same result whatever I throw in the fact table. The transaction table is setup with a relationship type of Fact. setup: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/119057/871760/B6YIBkzJyhLidSl/setup.png results: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/119057/871760/X3YwfzlfxfhjcNA/results.png Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, you will have to set relationships to other dimensions. But I am not sure which, as you dis not state anything about these requirements in your question. Could you please edit that and state how you want the other dimensions to affect the calculation?

Comment: Ideally I would like it to just relate to what ever else is selected in the query. Is that possible, or do I need to provide specific dimensions that it can relate to?

Comment: Never mind, I sorted it now. I just added a Many-to-many relationship in dimension usage, to the ones that was needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks Frank, your suggestion helped me sort out a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try this which should give you the average of that attribute across all members.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Booking Window Value] AS
[Booking Header].[Booking Window].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE
MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Booking Window Value] AS
AVG([Booking Header].[Booking Window].[Booking Window].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Booking Window Value])
SELECT
[Measures].[Avg Booking Window Value] ON COLUMNS
FROM
[YourCube]
```

Hope that helps and apologies for any confusion on my part.

Ash

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the same idea, but without success. The solution I found was create a view with the calculated average and include a new group of measures.