# can't figure out how to assign column from Dim table to measures group

Tags: t-sql, ssas, data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube

[image]DW is written in foreign language so i translated it on pictures.
It is about some facility where you can rent rooms and equipment.
In Fact table i have one measure column which represents number of reservations and it works as expected, problem is in DimPayment table i have columns PaymentSum and PaymentSumWDiscount which i would need to use as measures. i tried to do something  in calculations tab but i only get null values
I can't figure out how to use columns PaymentSum and PaymentSumWDiscount
as measures

i tried to do something  in calculations tab but i only get null values

[image]

Comment: are you trying to use your "dimension attribute" as a "measure". See whether it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122118/ssas-dimension-attribute-as-calculated-measure.

Normally, measures are in Fact tables (not dimension tables).

Comment: Hi! i am aware that measures are put in fact table and i had version of this project where column "paymentTotal" which was sum of few numabers was placed in Fact table as measure.i thought i works perfect. on the end my enitire BI project got rejected. because using it that way may create false values when browsing project. this version of DW got aproved so i am trying to make it work somehow

Answer (score 0):

JOIN the `FactReserving` table to the `DimPayment` table in the Data Source View and then you can access those two columns in the Measure group.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, it is already joined and i can add both columns as measures but when i try to use it with other table(for example rooms) in browser i get same number for all rooms(sum of all rezervations)

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a problem with how you set up your cube dimensions, which isn't shown in your question.

Comment: can you tell me what i can look for in cube dimensions, measure numberOfReservations works perfect with every dimension

Comment: In that case, maybe it's something else.   You would need to post enough info to reproduce the issue.  Tables, data, SSAS etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use your Dimension attributes as measure.

One way to achieve this is to make your Dimension table as a Measure Group as well.

The following example works with the AdventureWorks sample to create a measure group for the Product table:

In Visual Studio / SSDT, open your Cube, create a new Measure Group and select your table. (for your scenario, it would be the DimPayment table).

Your dimension usage mapping for this would be 'Fact' as both your fact and dimension are in the same table.

Now, you should be able to use the measures normally.

[image]

[image]

All the numeric fields automatically added as measures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using it as a measure:
[image]

[image]